# HTTP2 Push with Google Cloud CDN?

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

Is it possible to use HTTP2 Push with Google Cloud CDN?  If so, is it smart enough to understand and use a push-manifest.json to do so?

Comment: I have no idea, but what did you try to find that out yourself? Some research results are always welcome in questions.

Comment: Mostly, I just read the docs and didn't see any reference to it.  I know the HTTPS/2 load balancer supports the link preload header method for telling it what files to push.  What I'm not sure about is whether there's a way to set that header from GC CDN so that the load balancer picks up on it and acts accordingly.

Comment: Currently, HTTP2 push communication with backend service is not available as stated in [this help center article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/). As it is a matter of high demand there is already [an open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/63253334) for it. I would suggest adding your comment in the feature request to get more attention to it.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure those references are out of date as I've successfully implemented HTTP2 Push using Google Container Engine with HTTPS Load Balancing.  Specifically, I used prpl-server-node and its ability to set link preload headers: https://github.com/Polymer/prpl-server-node/blob/master/README.md#link-preload-headers

Comment: I believe that is a workaround which you have mentioned as the feature request is currently been actively worked on.

Comment: Too bad that Cloud Load Balancer currently turns all requests into HTTP/1.1 so push stops working.

Comment: That shouldn't matter if you're setting the Link header correctly.